# How can I rewrite this series of equations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, products

I have the following series of equation:

$m_1=m_1$

$m_2=m_1q_1$

$m_3=m_1q_1q_2$

$m_4=m_1q_1q_2q_3$

and so on till some $i=M$.

What I want is to write this in one function such that by plugging in any $i$ it outputs me the corresponding right hand side of the function.

What I found is the following:

$m_i=m_1\prod_{2}^i (q_{i-1})$

However, this only holds for $i>1$.

It it possible to construct such a thing for all $i$>0?

Comment: The formula holds for $n=1$ also if you **define** $q_0$ as $1$.

Comment: Sorry the $n$ was a mistake there, it should have only said 2. I have edited the mistake. What happens if you plug in 1 for $i$ in the product sign? Meaning that the product goes from 2 till $i=1$. Does it then mathematically put the output that part as 1 or as 0 or as undefined? Because I wanted to know if it is possible without defining $q_0$ as 1.

Comment: The product should be from $1$ to $i$ instead of $2$ to $i$. If $q_0$ is taken as $1$ you are in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$m_i = m_1 \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} q_j$$ holds for all $i>0$, under the convention that an empty product is $1$.

Comment: And it should be noted that the empty product being $1$ is the standard convention, not something specific to this problem.